# How to run a python webite project from github?

Tags: python, web, github

Before I go any further, I have to say I have hardly any clue with python web development. I have used meteor.js in the past for my database related projects.

I saw this project at a hackathon that was pure genius and in order to test it out, they put a link to their github. I went to their github https://github.com/xuyuwei/price-tracker
 and I don't know what to do next.

Could anyone give me any guidance as to what to do?

Answer (score 3):

First install dependencies

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then in Python

```
import app
app.run()
```

should do the trick.

(And he should probably change his Postgres password)

Comment: Looks more like flask based on `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Right, I just looked at the file structure

Comment: secrets.py is soooo bad

Comment: @Krumelur I have pip installed, but i got an error

`Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/y3/f9pcg3vs1n98jwff1fh9zr1m0000gn/T/pip-build-y0brb9/SQLAlchemy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/y3/f9pcg3vs1n98jwff1fh9zr1m0000gn/T/pip-6lEITN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/y3/f9pcg3vs1n98jwff1fh9zr1m0000gn/T/pip-build-y0brb9/SQLAlchemy`

Comment: Did you have a C compiler installed?